# T-SQL Find value in one column in different column on different row

Tags: sql-server, compare, case

This is difficult one to explain, so I'll do my best.

I have this table (other cols exist but irrelevant to my query).

```
CREATE TABLE ClientRelationships
(
    Client1 VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    Client2 VARCHAR(10) NULL
)

INSERT INTO ClientRelationships (Client1, Client2)
VALUES ('C12345', 'C67890'),
       ('C54353', 'C76345'),
       ('C76345', 'C54353'),
       ('C73246', NULL), 
       ('C67890', 'C12345')
```

| Client1 | Client2 |
| --- | --- |
| C12345 | C67890 |
| C54353 | C76345 |
| C76345 | C54353 |
| C73246 | NULL |
| C67890 | C12345 |

As you can see from the data, there are rows where the Client1 value appears in another row as Client2. In these instances, what I am looking to do mark the first occurrence as "Primary" and the second occurrence as "Secondary" (where the Client1 value is in the Client2 column on a different row). Maybe just as a boolean column called "Primary" set to 0 or 1.

Where there is no value in the Client2 column (NULL) the Primary column would be set to 1

Result would hopefully look like this with my example data.

| Client1 | Client2 | Primary |
| --- | --- | --- |
| C12345 | C67890 | 1 |
| C54353 | C76345 | 1 |
| C76345 | C54353 | 0 |
| C73246 | NULL | 1 |
| C67890 | C12345 | 0 |

Hope this makes sense.

I'm using SQL Server 2019, but anything from 2012 and above can be catered for as I have instances of all.

The records do not always appear concurrently in the table.

I am really unsure how to approach this so looking for some advice.

Comment: Is there a column, like an ID or a date that defines the order of the rows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is column that defines the order of the rows, like an `ID`, then you can do it with a `CASE` expression and `EXISTS`:

```
SELECT c1.*,
       CASE 
         WHEN EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM ClientRelationships c2 WHERE c2.ID < c1.ID AND c2.Client2 = c1.Client1) THEN 0
         ELSE 1
       END [Primary]
FROM ClientRelationships c1
```

Or, with a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT c1.*,
       (
         SELECT COALESCE(MAX(0), 1) 
         FROM ClientRelationships c2 
         WHERE c2.ID < c1.ID AND c2.Client2 = c1.Client1
       ) [Primary]
FROM ClientRelationships c1
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=8614994eb0274442a6e2fabc437c2120).

Comment: Thanks forpas, this is exactly what I need. There isn't an ID column unfortunately (this came from a CSV file), but I can add one in using  row_number(). This is my code now and it works fine.

`;WITH c1 AS
    (
    SELECT 
     ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Client1) AS ID
     , Client1, Client2
    FROM ClientRelationships
    )
    SELECT c1.*,
           CASE 
             WHEN EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM c1 c2 WHERE c2.ID < c1.ID AND c2.Client2 = c1.Client1) THEN 0
             ELSE 1
           END [Primary]
    FROM c1`